# Spring Boot-unable to process com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.ImgTagWorker

Tags: spring-boot, itext

While using IText to process HTML to create a PDF file I get the following error in the logger:

Unable to retrieve image with given base URI (file:/home/ms_user/ieco-service/pdf/) and image source path ()
Worker of type com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.DivTagWorker unable to process com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.ImgTagWorker
Unable to retrieve image with given base URI (file:/home/ms_user/ieco-service/pdf/) and image source path ()
Worker of type com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.DivTagWorker unable to process com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.ImgTagWorker

The error is not a typical stack trace error, just a single in the logger. It also doesn't stop execution, and a PDF is generated eventually. Both my HTML and PDF files are rather large, so it's difficult to check piece by piece, but a quick look doesn't seem to show any actual errors in the target file.

Is there a specific reason why this error happens/is shown? And will it eventually prevent a PDF file from being generated?

Comment: Those errors happen because pdfHTML failed to resolve images at the paths it expected to. It may be a problem of your HTML file (and accompanying resources) or of the pdfHTML settings you use. Those errors don't prevent PDF files from being generated - as you have seen, those are log messages